# Force AndroidStudio & Gradle to ndk{} use my Android.mk?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am wondering if there is any to ask AndridStudio to use my own Android.mk file?

I am asking this because my jni code is kind of massing up that inlcude source code of my other project (outside of the jni folder). I have managed it to work correctly by my own Android.mk file. However, after certain update, it seems Gradle's "ndk {}" will create their own version of Android.mk and ruin my project.

For example, the following is the example of my jni code structure:

```
|- other_project/
|   |- includes/
|   |- other_code.cpp
|
|- android_project
    |- app/src/main/
                |- java/
                |- jni/
                    |- Android.mk
                    |- Application.mk
                    |- code.cpp
```

and my own Android.mk

```
// ... some other settings ...
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
    $(LOCAL_PATH) \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../other_project/include/
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    ../../../../other_project/other_code.cpp \
    code.cpp
```

In my build.gradle:

```
ndk {
        moduleName = "xxxx" // module for standalone processing
        ldLibs "log"
        stl "stlport_shared"
        cFlags "-DDEV_NDK=1 -v"
    }
```

I know this is using the other Android.mk (auto-generated based on the ndk setting) because some of my customized c flags (in my own Android.mk) is missing until I add the cFlags field in the ndk {}.

So my question is: **if there is any way I can force the ndk{} to use my Android.mk to build? or, how can I add a proper options in the ndk {} to generate a similar Android.mk that can include .cpp/.h files outside the jni folder?**

Comment: Any particular readon for not using `externalNativeBuild`? (in which case you'd specify the makefile with `android { externalNativeBuild { ndkBuild { path "bla/bla/Android.mk" } } }`

Comment: Hi externalNativeBuild will work. In my test externalNativeBuild use my Android.mk to compile. Thank you!